# Uniform price vs discriminatory price double auction

Tags: supply-and-demand, auctions, energy-economics, trading

Uniform price and discriminatory price double auctions are the most commonly used auction mechanisms in the trading markets especially in peer-to-peer energy trading markets. However, I could not find which one is the better option in this particular domain. Can someone provide a comparative analysis of both auctions mechanisms?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the main reason why you could not find an answer is that economists do not know, see, for instance this [chapter](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-36979-8_2) of ["Electricity Markets."](https://www.springerprofessional.de/en/electricity-markets/17786714)
The auction theorist Peter Cramton has [a few papers on this](http://www.cramton.umd.edu/papers/electricity/).